# Limit of an sequence

Tags: limits

i can't figure out, how to find the Limit of that sequence.

$$a_n=\sqrt[n]{e^n+n(13+\sin(n))}$$

Comment: What did you try? Did you at least factorize by $e^n$ ?

Comment: What is the dominant term under the radical ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$12\le13+\sin(n)\le14$$

Thus,

$$e=\sqrt[n]{e^n+0}\le\sqrt[n]{e^n+12n}\le\sqrt[n]{e^n+n(13+\sin(n))}\\\sqrt[n]{e^n+n(13+\sin(n))}\le\sqrt[n]{e^n+14n}\le\sqrt[n]{e^n+e^n}=e\sqrt[n]2$$

Now use the fact that $\sqrt[n]2\to1$ to see by squeeze theorem that the limit is $e$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: write $$a_n=e\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{n(13+\sin(n)}{e^n}}$$